# Migrating existing BigQuery datasets to Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Background:

I'm new to Terraform but an active BigQuery user. We have an existing BigQuery project that has > 100 datasets and we want to start using Terraform to control access (dataset level only, not table or column level) as manually assigning access using the UI is no longer scalable. Our plan is to implement Terraform on 5 datasets and over time add datasets so as to eventually include every dataset in the project.

Problem:

I'm struggling to figure out how to import all these datasets automatically before running `terraform apply`. My `main.tf` file contains 5 blocks like this:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset_1" {
  dataset_id    = "dataset_1"
  location      = local.location
  project       = local.project_id

  access {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to run `terraform import` to automatically import all datasets listed in `main.tf`?

Notes:

- I don't want to create or destroy any resources, all datasets already exist.
- `terraform` commands will be run locally on MacOS.

Comment: You could probably import the datasets, but I'm not sure if there's a bulk action for that. Here's the Terraform documentation for BigQuery import: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset#import.

Comment: @MarkoE Yes, I've tried this, there appears to be no bulk import option. Additionally when fully rolled out I do not want to have to import > 100 datasets every time I run the `terraform` commands. It would be great if there was a command to see what resources are in the `main.tf` file and import only those resources.

Comment: You could try and "capture" the state at a certain point with `terraform state show` and see which resources are present.

Comment: @MarkoE How would I use this? I can run `terraform state show` and see the 5 datasets I've imported and successfully updated via Terraform. Adding a 6th dataset will not affect the contents of `terraform state show` unless I import this 6th dataset, defeating the purpose of this which is to automatically import datasets listed in the `main.tf` file.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I don't think you can import resources just by listing them inside the `main.tf`. IIRC, newer versions might consider adding the automatic addition of resources based on the configuration from the Terraform file, if I understood you correctly. https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html#currently-state-only

Comment: @MarkoE OK, yes I saw that note though I've no idea when this feature will be released. Hopefully someone else has a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Usually I run the command terraform plan to check the resources. So I write/fix the code in some *.tf and import the state.

For import the state for Bigquery dataset will be some of this options:

```
$ terraform import google_bigquery_dataset.default projects/{{project}}/datasets/{{dataset_id}}
$ terraform import google_bigquery_dataset.default {{project}}/{{dataset_id}}
$ terraform import google_bigquery_dataset.default {{dataset_id}}
```

After that you will recive a message like that:

```
Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Comment: I must say that the Haschicorp documentation here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/bigquery_dataset is missing the import command syntax, for once...